# word vba replace docvariable by text and then remove the docvariable and keep the text

Tags: vba, ms-word, docvariable

I have a word template containing docvariables. With an Access application, I can open the template, set a value to each docvariable fields and then save as the document.

These docvariables will not need to be modified in the future.

Therefore I would like to find a way, with vba, to keep the replacement text but remove the docvariable, as if the text was entered manually. So there would not be a grey background behind replaced docvariables, and Alt+F9 would not show anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use bookmarks instead. They are visible as grey vertical lines or grey brackets. Usually they are invisible until You toggle their visibility in settings. Depending on the type of the bookmark You can try something like this:

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bestBookmarkName").Range.InsertAfter "necessary text"
```